# Aligning text and image in an SWT Button?

Tags: java, swt

I'm using SWT in Java and I'm trying to left align an image and text that I have inside an SWT Button. It seems like it should be a simple button.setAlignment(SWT.LEFT) call, but that isn't working. A quick Google search leads me to believe this may be a bug in the SWT framework. Does anyone have any help on this?

Comment: For those with this problem, I "solved it" by extending SWT Composite and had that contain a Label (the image) and a Button (the button with text). Extending SWT is generally not a supported feature, so you may need to override the checkSubclass() method. Again, according to the SWT developers, this is unsupported and potentially unsafe, so becareful with this.

Comment: A sample code would be nice for all of us to use. Right now, any of us that would like this fix, has to reinvent the wheel. Also, I am using 4.3 final (June 5, 2013) from a year ago, and still no update. Nobody seems to be in any rush considering that 5 years passed by since this post, almost to the month.

Comment: An alternative which involves custom painting is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834367/java-swt-button-with-text-over-image (though this describes drawing the text above an image, but the principle is the same)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be an SWT limitation (at least in Windows).

Prior to 3.2, setting both an Image and Text on a button was not possible.  Reading through that [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=33967), there was some discussion given to alignment and relative positioning of the image to the text.  It appears that the final implementation simply forced a center alignment, and placed the image to the left of the text.

There was an enhancement request to fix this limitation, [but it was closed as WONTFIX for 3.3](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=172850).

Comment: Yeah, this was what I was left with too. Alright, I will go with this. I have a "work-around" which I'll post in a comment to my question.