# Java SWT Button with text OVER image

Tags: java, image, button, text, swt

SWT does not support "Text over Image" in a Button. When the Image is set, hides the text. What could be the best approach to achieve this?

The best workaround i could think of was to "merge" the text with the image... does anyone know a good Java library do to this?

NOTE: I've found this custom implementation that simply draws the Text over the Image: https://github.com/jrobichaux/SquareButton/wiki. Why is this not implemented in SWT?? (anyway, i could not make this class work... and i really don't want this approach because i want the NATIVE Button look)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is this not implemented in SWT?

SWT aims at looking native. To achieve this, SWT uses OS resources for the widgets. Consequently, the SWT `Button`s look like the OS buttons. Buttons with text above or below images are not quite common.

I managed to achieve something that somehow works, but it's quite hacky. Maybe you can use it as a starting point:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    final Image image = display.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_ERROR);
    final String text = "Button";

    final Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);

    GridData data = new GridData();
    float fontHeight = shell.getFont().getFontData()[0].height;
    data.heightHint = image.getImageData().height + (int)fontHeight + 20;
    data.widthHint = 100;

    button.setLayoutData(data);

    button.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            GC gc = event.gc;

            int width = ((GridData)button.getLayoutData()).widthHint;
            int height = ((GridData)button.getLayoutData()).heightHint;
            Point textSize = gc.textExtent(text);

            gc.drawText(text, width / 2 - textSize.x / 2, image.getImageData().height - image.getImageData().height / 2 - textSize.y, true);
            gc.drawImage(image, width / 2 - image.getImageData().width / 2, height / 2 - image.getImageData().height / 2 + textSize.y / 2);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    image.dispose();
    display.dispose();
}
```

As you can see, I used `GridData` to achieve the sizing of the button and a `Listener` for `SWT.Paint` to fill the button with the image and the text.

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My goal is to achieve text OVER image (not above or bellow). There is no reason why the SWT implementation cannot suport this feature. If the SO can natively display an image, SWT could "merge" the text over the image...

Comment: @marcolopes You can display the text over the image by just changing the coordinates of `drawText` and `drawImage` and reversing their order.